# How to connect to Snowflake using RIDE IDE of robot framework

Tags: snowflake-connector, ride

I have been trying to do a DB validating on Snowflake. But Cannot find the proper keywords to connect. I have installed snowflake-connector. But not able to get the script. I have tried below code and imported snowflake library too at Project and Suit levels/

```
    ctx_QAT_ONEWM_UIPARAMS = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='****', # enter userID here
    password='****', # Enter Password here
    account='*****',
    warehouse='******',
    database='*****',
    schema='****',
    role= '*****',
    authenticator='externalbrowser',
    )
    cs_QAT_ONEWM_UIPARAMS = ctx_QAT_ONEWM_UIPARAMS.cursor()
    print("DB Session Started")
    try:
    cs_QAT_ONEWM_UIPARAMS.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs_QAT_ONEWM_UIPARAMS.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
    finally:
    cs.close()
    ctx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to connect using an externalbrowser authentication with two differences:

- using `dbname` instead of `database`
- excluding the password. It is not needed when using externalbrowser if the browser stores it

Alternatively, I'm able to connect using a system user with a private key with a password as the `private_key` parameter, using the default `authenticator`